# CRM Dynamics Plugin Error - Given Key not found in Dictionary

Tags: dictionary, plugins, key, crm, microsoft-dynamics

Hi i developed a plugin and once deployed, i'm getting an error on save of a record. 
Given key was not found in Dictionary. It's a pretty generic error, do you see anything or possibly know of a way to go about debugging ? `

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query;
using Quad.SalesEstimating.MSCRMPlugins.PluginHelpers;
using Sybase.Data.AseClient;

namespace CRMSolution.Plugins
{
    public class PreTitleUpdate : IPlugin
    {

        public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)
                serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));

            Entity entity;

            if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") &&
                context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity)
            {
                // Obtain the target business entity from the input parmameters.
                entity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];

                // Verify that the entity represents an contact.);
                if (entity.LogicalName != "qg_title") { return; }
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }

            try
            {
                IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)
                    serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
                IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(
                    context.UserId);
                IOrganizationService elevatedService = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(null);

                Entity preImage = context.PreEntityImages["PreImage"];
                //Entity postImage = context.PostEntityImages["PostImage"];

                #region Variable Setup

                const string PREMEDIA_PC = "100000000";
                const string RETAIL_INSERTS_PC = "9";
                const string COMMERCIAL_PC = "12";
                const string DIRECT_MAIL_PC = "7";
                const string INSTORE_PC = "13";

                string creditAccountID = null;
                string creditCustomerID = null;
                //string previousTitleCode = null;

                string accountId = null;
                string creditId = null;

                string productType = string.Empty;
                int vertisId = 0;
                string vertisCustId = string.Empty;
                string vertisParentCustId = string.Empty;
                string message = string.Empty;

                #endregion

                #region Get Entity Values

                EntityReference titleidLookup = new EntityReference();
                if (entity.Contains("qg_titleid"))
                {
                    var titleGuid = (Guid)entity["qg_titleid"];
                    titleidLookup = (EntityReference)new EntityReference("qg_title", titleGuid);
                }
                else if (preImage.Contains("qg_titleid"))
                {
                    var titleGuid = (Guid)preImage["qg_titleid"];
                    titleidLookup = (EntityReference)new EntityReference("qg_title", titleGuid);
                }


                EntityReference accountIdLookup = new EntityReference();
                if (entity.Contains("qg_accountid"))
                {
                    accountIdLookup = (EntityReference)entity["qg_accountid"];
                    accountId = accountIdLookup.Id.ToString();
                }
                else if (preImage.Contains("qg_accountid"))
                {
                    accountIdLookup = (EntityReference)preImage["qg_accountid"];
                    accountId = accountIdLookup.Id.ToString();
                }

                EntityReference creditIdLookup = new EntityReference();
                if (entity.Contains("qg_creditid"))
                {
                    creditIdLookup = (EntityReference)entity["qg_creditid"];

                    if (creditIdLookup != null)
                    {
                        creditId = creditIdLookup.Id.ToString();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        entity.SetValue("qg_customerid", string.Empty);
                    }
                }
                else if (preImage.Contains("qg_creditid"))
                {
                    creditIdLookup = (EntityReference)preImage["qg_creditid"];

                    if (creditIdLookup != null)
                    {
                        creditId = creditIdLookup.Id.ToString();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        entity.SetValue("qg_customerid", string.Empty);
                    }
                }

                //if (entity.Contains("qg_previoustitlecode"))
                //{
                //    previousTitleCode = entity.GetValue("qg_previoustitlecode");
                //}
                //else if (preImage.Contains("qg_previoustitlecode"))
                //{
                //    previousTitleCode = preImage.GetValue("qg_previoustitlecode");
                //}

                if (entity.Contains("qg_producttype"))
                {
                    productType = entity.GetValue("qg_producttype");
                    //this.LogItemToFile("QG_TitlePreUpdate productType from entity.");
                }
                else if (preImage.Contains("qg_producttype"))
                {
                    productType = preImage.GetValue("qg_producttype");
                    //this.LogItemToFile("QG_TitlePreUpdate productType from preImage.");
                }

                if (entity.Contains("qg_vertiscustomerid"))
                {
                    vertisCustId = entity.GetValue("qg_vertiscustomerid");
                    //this.LogItemToFile("QG_TitlePreUpdate qg_vertiscustomerid from entity.");
                }
                else if (preImage.Contains("qg_vertiscustomerid"))
                {
                    vertisCustId = preImage.GetValue("qg_vertiscustomerid");
                    //this.LogItemToFile("QG_TitlePreUpdate qg_vertiscustomerid from preImage.");
                }

                #endregion

                if (accountId != null)
                {

                    #region Credit Business Unit

                    if (creditId != null)
                    {
                        // get credit business unit
                        ColumnSet creditcolumns = new ColumnSet(new string[] {"qg_accountid", "qg_customerid"});
                        Guid creditIdGUID = new Guid(creditId);
                        Entity qg_credit = elevatedService.Retrieve("qg_credit", creditIdGUID, creditcolumns);
                        if (qg_credit.Attributes.Contains("qg_accountid"))
                        {
                            EntityReference creditAccount = (EntityReference)qg_credit["qg_accountid"];
                            creditAccountID = creditAccount.Id.ToString();
                        }
                        if (qg_credit.Attributes.Contains("qg_customerid"))
                        {
                            creditCustomerID = qg_credit.GetValue("qg_customerid").ToString();
                        }
                    }

                    #endregion

                    #region Validate Customer ID

                    // If the Customer has been selected, validate account and get the customer ID.
                    // Validate that the Credit record and Title are under the same Account

                    if (creditId != null)
                    {

                        if (creditAccountID != accountId)
                        {
                            throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(" " +
                                                                      "Credit Record must be under the same Account as the Title.");
                        }

                        if (creditCustomerID != null)
                        {
                            // Set the customerid on the Title
                            entity.SetValue("qg_customerid", creditCustomerID);
                            // service.Update(entity);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // something went wrong so stop processing...
                            throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(" " + "Could not update the Customer ID.");
                        }
                    }

                    #endregion

                    //#region Validate Previous Title Code

                    //// if a previous title code has been selected, validate that it exists...
                    //if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(previousTitleCode))
                    //{
                    //    if (!TitleCodeExists(previousTitleCode))
                    //    {
                    //        throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(" " + "Previous Title Code is not valid.  Please select a Title Code that previously existed.");
                    //    }
                    //}

                    //#endregion

                    #region Approved for QG Paper

                    try
                    {

                        string ownerDomainName = null;
                        string aprvdForQGPaper = "";

                        ColumnSet ownerColumns = new ColumnSet(new string[] { "businessunitid", "domainname", });
                        Entity systemuser = service.Retrieve("systemuser", context.InitiatingUserId, ownerColumns);

                        if (entity.Contains("qg_aprvdforqgppr"))
                        {
                            aprvdForQGPaper = entity.GetValue("qg_aprvdforqgppr");
                        }

                        if (systemuser.Attributes.Contains("domainname"))
                        {
                            ownerDomainName = systemuser.GetValue("domainname").ToString();
                        }

                        // Set the Approved for QG Paper last changed
                        if (aprvdForQGPaper == "1")
                        {
                            entity.SetValue("qg_aprvdforqgpprdt", DateTime.Now);
                            entity.SetValue("qg_aprvdforqgpprby", ownerDomainName);
                        }

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(
                            " " + "An error occurred in the plug-in." + ex.Message, ex);
                    }

                    #endregion

                    #region Validate Classification

                    //try
                    //{
                    //    if (entity.Contains("qg_producttype") && preImage.Contains("qg_producttype"))
                    //    {
                    //        bool validateProdType = true;

                    //        // Allow Credit to change product type regardless of Sales Staff being assigned.
                    //        if (this.DoesUserHaveRole(context.InitiatingUserId, service, "Quad Credit") ||
                    //            this.DoesUserHaveRole(context.InitiatingUserId, service, "System Administrator"))
                    //        {
                    //            validateProdType = false;
                    //        }

                    //        if (validateProdType)
                    //        {
                    //            OptionSetValue preProdType = (OptionSetValue)preImage["qg_producttype"];
                    //            OptionSetValue postProdType = (OptionSetValue)entity["qg_producttype"];

                    //            if (preProdType.Value != postProdType.Value)
                    //            {
                    //                // The only valid Product Classification change is within MagCat/SIP.
                    //                List<int> validprodclasschangelist = new List<int>(new int[] { 2, 3, 5 });

                    //                List<int> salesRoles = new List<int>(new int[] { 52, 30, 33, 35, 41, 48 });

                    //                QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression();
                    //                query.NoLock = true;
                    //                ColumnSet columns = new ColumnSet(new string[] { "qg_titleid", "qg_employeerole" });
                    //                ConditionExpression condition = new ConditionExpression();

                    //                condition.AttributeName = "qg_employeerole";
                    //                condition.Operator = ConditionOperator.In;
                    //                foreach (var role in salesRoles)
                    //                {
                    //                    condition.Values.Add(role);
                    //                }

                    //                query.EntityName = "qg_titleemployeerole";
                    //                query.ColumnSet = columns;
                    //                query.Criteria.AddCondition("qg_titleid", ConditionOperator.Equal, titleidLookup.Id);
                    //                query.Criteria.AddCondition(condition);

                    //                EntityCollection resultSet = service.RetrieveMultiple(query);

                    //                if (resultSet.Entities.Count > 0)
                    //                {
                    //                    if (!validprodclasschangelist.Contains(preProdType.Value) ||
                    //                        !validprodclasschangelist.Contains(postProdType.Value))
                    //                    {
                    //                        throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("Product Classification change is not valid.");
                    //                    }
                    //                }
                    //            }
                    //        }

                    //    }                                                      
                    //}
                    //catch (Exception ex)
                    //{
                    //    throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(
                    //        " " + "An error occurred in the plug-in." + ex.Message, ex);
                    //}

                    #endregion

                    #region Vertis Ids


                    string accountBUID = null;
                    string accountBUName = null;

                    // if the account doesn't have a VertisParentCustomerID get the last five digits of the VMAC ID 
                    //  to build the parent customer id 
                    ColumnSet accountcolumns = new ColumnSet(new string[] { "owningbusinessunit", "qg_vertisparentcustid" });
                    Guid accountIdGUID = new Guid(accountId);
                    Entity accountService = service.Retrieve("account", accountIdGUID, accountcolumns);

                    if (accountService.Attributes.Contains("owningbusinessunit"))
                    {
                        EntityReference accountBusinessUnit = (EntityReference)accountService["owningbusinessunit"];
                        accountBUID = accountBusinessUnit.Id.ToString();
                    }

                    if (accountService.Attributes.Contains("qg_vertisparentcustid"))
                    {
                        vertisParentCustId = accountService.GetValue("qg_vertisparentcustid");
                    }

                    ColumnSet buColumns = new ColumnSet(new string[] { "name" });
                    // GUID from above
                    Guid buIdGUID = new Guid(accountBUID);
                    Entity buService = service.Retrieve("businessunit", buIdGUID, buColumns);
                    if (buService.Attributes.Contains("name"))
                    {
                        accountBUName = buService.GetValue("name").ToString();
                    }


                    // if productClass has been selected, see if we need to pull VertisCustIds..
                    if (accountBUName.Equals("Corporate Print") && string.IsNullOrEmpty(vertisCustId))
                    {

                        // if product class is 'Retail Inserts', 'Premedia', or 'Commercial' we need to pull Vertis Ids
                        if (productType.Equals(RETAIL_INSERTS_PC) || productType.Equals(DIRECT_MAIL_PC) ||
                            productType.Equals(COMMERCIAL_PC) || productType.Equals(PREMEDIA_PC) || productType.Equals(INSTORE_PC))
                        {
                            bool vertisIdResult = false;

                            // get the last five digits of the VMAC ID to build the customer id
                            vertisIdResult = this.GetNextId("VERTIS_CUST_ID", "TITLE", ref vertisId, ref message);

                            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(vertisParentCustId))
                            {
                                // get the last five digits of the VMAC ID to build the parent customer id
                                //vertisIdResult = this.GetNextId("VERTIS_CUST_ID", "TITLE", ref vertisId, ref message);

                                accountService.SetValue("qg_vertisparentcustid", "9" + vertisId.ToString());
                                service.Update(accountService);
                            }

                            if (vertisIdResult)
                            {
                                if (productType.Equals(DIRECT_MAIL_PC))
                                {
                                    vertisCustId = "5" + vertisId.ToString();
                                }
                                else if (productType.Equals(RETAIL_INSERTS_PC))
                                {
                                    vertisCustId = "0" + vertisId.ToString();
                                }
                                else { vertisCustId = "1" + vertisId.ToString(); }

                                //this.LogItemToFile("TitlePreCreate vertisCustId: " + vertisCustId);

                                entity.SetValue("qg_vertiscustomerid", vertisCustId);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(vertisCustId))
                    {
                        // if the product class changed, we may need to change the VertisCustomerID
                        if (entity.Contains("qg_producttype") && preImage.Contains("qg_producttype"))
                        {
                            OptionSetValue preProdType = (OptionSetValue)preImage["qg_producttype"];
                            OptionSetValue postProdType = (OptionSetValue)entity["qg_producttype"];

                            if (preProdType.Value != postProdType.Value)
                            {
                                //if (Convert.ToInt32(vertisCustId.Substring(1)) < 67000)
                                //{
                                //    throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(" " + "Product Class may not be changed for Customers that originated from Vertis.");
                                //}
                                //else
                                //{
                                    // check the validity of the VertisId
                                    //    if (productType.Equals(DIRECT_MAIL_PC)) vertisCustId = "5" + vertisId.ToString();
                                    //    if (productType.Equals(RETAIL_INSERTS_PC)) vertisCustId = "0" + vertisId.ToString();
                                    //    else { vertisCustId = "1" + vertisId.ToString(); 
                                    if (productType.Equals(DIRECT_MAIL_PC) && !vertisCustId.Substring(0, 1).Equals("5"))
                                    {
                                        vertisCustId = vertisCustId.Substring(1);
                                        vertisCustId = "5" + vertisCustId;
                                        entity.SetValue("qg_vertiscustomerid", vertisCustId);
                                    }
                                    else if (productType.Equals(RETAIL_INSERTS_PC) && !vertisCustId.Substring(0, 1).Equals("0"))
                                    {
                                        vertisCustId = vertisCustId.Substring(1);
                                        vertisCustId = "0" + vertisCustId;
                                        entity.SetValue("qg_vertiscustomerid", vertisCustId);
                                    }
                                    else if (productType.Equals(PREMEDIA_PC) && !vertisCustId.Substring(0, 1).Equals("1"))
                                    {
                                        vertisCustId = vertisCustId.Substring(1);
                                        vertisCustId = "1" + vertisCustId;
                                        entity.SetValue("qg_vertiscustomerid", vertisCustId);
                                    }
                                //} 
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    #endregion

                }
                else
                {
                    throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(" " + "An error occurred in the plug-in. Owner ID, Account ID or Credit ID is Null.");
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(" " + "An error occurred in the plug-in." + ex.Message, ex);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Use Ase command to determine is title code exists
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="titlecode">The title code to use in the select </param>
        /// <returns>A true/false value indicating success or failure</returns>
        public bool TitleCodeExists(string titlecode)
        {
            int TitleCodeCount = 0;
            string CmndText = "select count(*) as cnt from QUAD0024.dbo.TITLE_VW where _TITLE_CODE = '" + titlecode + "'";

            // connect to Sybase to see if Title Code exists in the Title View.
            try
            {
                using (AseConnection dbcon = new AseConnection(this.GetSybaseDbConnectionString()))
                {

                    dbcon.Open();
                    AseCommand cmd = new AseCommand(CmndText, dbcon);
                    IDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        TitleCodeCount = (int)reader["cnt"];
                    }

                    if (TitleCodeCount == 0)
                    {
                        //throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(" " + " TitleCodeExists: Return False.");
                        return false; 
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(" " + " TitleCodeExists: Return True.");
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                this.LogExceptionEvent(new Exception("Message", e));
                throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(" " + " TitleCodeExists Failed" + e.Message);
            }
        }

    }
}

`
```

Comment: Use a Plugin Profiler (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328574.aspx) would work for both online and on-prem. If you are on-prem you can use visual stuido remote-debugger by copying your plugin dlls to the SDK bin folder, like you would any remote application.

Comment: We are running on i think 2011.

Answer (score 1):

Its better to check before we are trying to access any attribute in an object.

In this particular code, one catch is that while accessing the images we are not trying to check whether the object contains that image or not. 
Similar way check any other miss.

It may also be possible that we are checking for a particular attribute and accessing a different one because of a typo.

Hope this helps you to pin point the issue.

Comment: Hi - thanks for the response. How can I check if the object contains it before trying to access it?

This is similar to a null check then, i'm going to assume.

Comment: You can use the Contains method to check something like below

context.PreEntityImages.Contains("<<Your image name>>");

This is the same way how we does the checking for attributes. Hope this helps.